# DataTables.net in React - Tooltip on header column cell needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatables

I am using a datatables.net table inside a React app. I want to know how I can create a tooltip on the header of the 'Effective Year Built' column.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setupTable(this.props.data);
}

setupTable(data) {

    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.DataTable(
        {
            alternatingRowStyle: true,
            sort: 'enable'
            data: data,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Search"
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    "title": "Parcel ID",
                    mData: "ParcelID"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Land Value",
                    mData: "TotalLandValue",
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '', 0, '$')
                },
                {
                    "title": "Effective Year Built",
                    mData: "effectiveyearbuilt"
                }
            ]
        }
    )
}
```

I have tried a number of solutions to no avail. I don't seem to be able to tag a unique id into that particular cell either? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've used datatables with React and have added styles to the columns by specifying a class name in the column definition.  Maybe you could a class name and then use CSS for the tooltip as per https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is how I fixed it :) -- "title": "<span class='d-inline-block' tabindex='0' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Estimated effective age of the improvement.'>Effective Year Built</span>",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to assign an attribute (`id`, in your case) to your column header node, you may do that with something, like:

```
$(dataTable.column(2).header()).attr('id', '/* some id here */');
```

where dataTable is a variable, returned by `DataTable()` constructor

Comment: Thanks Yevgen, I did alter the column header node by adding in the "title": "<span class='d-inline-block' tabindex='0' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Estimated effective age of the improvement.'>Effective Year Built</span>"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you might benefit from pulling in a package like `react-table` [(react-table)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) - I've used this before in a project, and it works really nicely. You are able to define custom rendered components - which you can just go and grab another package `react-tooltip` [(react-tooltip)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip) for.

I find it a bit easier to work with React specific node packages instead of pulling in JS libraries, where possible.

Comment: Yes I completely agree and do know that I ought not to be mixing jQuery with React as a lot of care needs to be taken to keep the tables DOM and React's DOM separate. Using it was a requirement unfortunately.